# I need help with tikz tree node and label, offsets and inclination

Tags: tikz-trees

I need to draw something like this:

My problem are the black dots position i.e. nodes S and M and the labels position, also the number labels does not look good too.

The X node is beside Coke node not in the edge between Cabonated_Drinks and Coke.

[image]

this is what i got:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzset{
        level 1/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=45mm},
        level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm},
        level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm},
        level 4/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
    }

    \node(A)[hollow node,label=above:{ALL}]{}
    child {
        %node(B)[hollow node,label=left:{Carbonated Drinks}]{}
        node(B)[hollow node,label={[align=left]left:Carbonated\\Drinks}]{}
        child {node(D)[hollow node, label=below:{Coke}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[solid node, left, label=left:{X}, at end]{}
                node[right]{1}
            }
        }
        child {node(E)[hollow node, label=below:{Pepsi}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[left]{1}
                node[solid node, right, near start, label=right:{T}]{}
            }
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[solid node, left, near start, label=left:{S}]{}
            node[solid node, right, near start, label=right:{M}]{}
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[right]{1}
        }
    }
    child {
        node(C)[hollow node,label=right:{Coffee}]{}
        child {
            node(F)[hollow node, label=below:{Mocca}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[right]{1}
            }
        }
        child {
            node(G)[hollow node, label=below:{Nescaffe}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[left]{1}
            }
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[left]{1}
        }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What gives me an image like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! And the proble you have are the positions of the black points? Please do not only show a image and some code, explain your problem in words too!

Comment: [edited] My problem are the black dots position and the labels position, also the number labels does not look good too.

Comment: You can add `above` or `below` or `xshift=...mm` or `yshift=...mm` into node definitions for black dots positions.

Comment: It's not customary to add “SOLVED” to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two keys which might be useful here: `pos` and `shift`. Using these, I got

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzset{
        level 1/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=45mm},
        level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm},
        level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm},
        level 4/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
    }

    \node(A)[hollow node,label=above:{ALL}]{}
    child {
        %node(B)[hollow node,label=left:{Carbonated Drinks}]{}
        node(B)[hollow node,label={[align=left,xshift=1.5em]135:Carbonated\\Drinks}]{}
        child {node(D)[hollow node, label=below:{Coke}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[solid node,pos=0.95,xshift=-0.5em,left, label=left:{X}]{}
                node[pos=0.6,above left]{1}
            }
        }
        child {node(E)[hollow node, label=below:{Pepsi}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[pos=0.6,below left]{1}
                node[solid node, right, pos=0.4, label=right:{T}]{}
            }
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[solid node, left, pos=0.35,shift={(120:2pt)}, label=120:{S}]{}
            node[solid node, right, pos=0.35,shift={(-60:2pt)}, label=-60:{M}]{}
            node[pos=0.6,above left]{1}
            }
    }
    child {
        node(C)[hollow node,label=right:{Coffee}]{}
        child {
            node(F)[hollow node, label=below:{Mocca}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[pos=0.6,above left]{1}
            }
        }
        child {
            node(G)[hollow node, label=below:{Nescaffe}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[pos=0.6,above right]{1}
            }
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[pos=0.6,above right]{1}
        }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the long run you may benefit from switching to forest.`

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED
using properly xshift and yshift with labels and nodes as @marmot says...

Here is the improved code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=2, fill=black, line width=1pt},
  hollow node/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=2, line width=1pt },
}

%child{node(l1)[hollow node, label=below:{D}]{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzset{
        level 1/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=45mm, line width=1pt},
        level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm},
        level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm},
        level 4/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
    }

    \node(A)[hollow node,label=above:{ALL}]{}
    child {
        %node(B)[hollow node,label=left:{Carbonated Drinks}]{}
        node(B)[hollow node,label={[align=left]left:Carbonated\\Drinks}]{}
        child {node(D)[hollow node, label=below:{Coke}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[solid node, xshift=-1pt, yshift=+3pt, left, label=left:{X}, at end]{}
                node[right]{1}
            }
        }
        child {node(E)[hollow node, label=below:{Pepsi}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[left]{1}
                node[solid node, rotate=+45pt, right, near start, label={[xshift=-1.0pt, yshift=-9.0pt]right:T}]{}
            }
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[solid node, rotate=-45, left, near start,label={[xshift=2.0pt, yshift=-7.0pt]left:S}]{}
            node[solid node, rotate=-45, right, near start, label={[xshift=-2.0pt, yshift=7.0pt]right:M}]{}
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[right]{1}
        }
    }
    child {
        node(C)[hollow node,label=right:{Coffee}]{}
        child {
            node(F)[hollow node, label=below:{Mocca}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[right]{1}
            }
        }
        child {
            node(G)[hollow node, label=below:{Nescaffe}]{}
            edge from parent{
                node[left]{1}
            }
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[left]{1}
        }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got:

[image]

thanks all @marmot, @ferahfeza